# Dell laptop log in

Tags: keyboard, login, password

I have a Dell lap top with Ubuntu 18.04. I recently had a new keyboard fitted as a result of sticky keys. Now I am unable to login. I am convinced my password is correct, but no success. Any ideas on my problem please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At login page, press Ctrl + Alt + F3 to enter tty. Enter username and password then type "sudo rm -r ~/.local" to delete all the user-specific configurations and then reboot.

Comment: Thank you Edmund. Perfect, am up and running again

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any easy solution here. You can plug in an external keyboard.

If your hard disk is not encrypted, you can use a live CD to access your files without having to login.